# error reading select cases - excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code below and I can not get the following this statement to work:

```
If UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "LM" Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 3.5
```

the code will not execute anything from the above statement.

```
Case "L"


 **If UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "LM" Then
 If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) Then
            If Mid(Dn, 3, 1) = "0" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 3.5
           Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 0.35
           End If
            End If

    ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 5, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 5, 1) = "0" And Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
        If Dn.Offset(, 3) = "CMBS" Then
             Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 20
        Else
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 2
        End If

        ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 6)) Like "LM###S" Then

        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 2
        Else
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 0.2
        End If**



    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "L/M" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 3.5
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LM$" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 3.5
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "L$" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 3, 2)) + 2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LO-" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 6)) = "LO MID" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 7, 3)) + 3.5
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LO " Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 5)) Like "L###H" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 0.2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 4)) Like "L##H" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 2)) + 0.2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 4)) Like "L#" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 2)) + 0.2
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" And Mid(Dn, 3, 1) = "0" Then
            If Dn.Offset(, 3) = "CMBS" Then
                Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 20
            Else
                Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 2
            End If
        ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 5)) Like "L###S" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 2
        Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 0.2
        End If
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" And Mid(Dn, 3, 1) <> "0" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 0.2
        End If
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) Like "L##" Then
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) Then
            If Mid(Dn, 3, 1) = "0" Then
                Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 2
            Else
                Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 0.2
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

**input value -->

lm10, LM120S, 
LM120
desired output -->

13.5
123.5
120.35**

Any help with this issue would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Change `Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3))` to `Val(Mid(Dn, 3, 2))` and try again `EDIT:` Explanation: You want to pick up 10 which is at the 3rd place and is of 2 chars

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help.  I edit the code and adding new if statements to the LM select case and its not displaying any output. I can not figure out why its doing so.  Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: posted an answer after seinng your edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this code in a module

```
Public Function GetNumb(strString As String) As Double
    Dim strLen As Long, i As Long
    Dim Temp As String

    strLen = Len(strString): Temp = ""

    For i = 1 To strLen
        If (Mid(strString, i, 1) = "-") Then
            Temp = Temp & Mid(strString, i, 1)
        End If
        If (Mid(strString, i, 1) = ".") Then
            Temp = Temp & Mid(strString, i, 1)
        End If
        If (IsNumeric(Mid(strString, i, 1))) = True Then
            Temp = Temp & Mid(strString, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    If Len(Temp) = 0 Then
        GetNumb = 0
    Else
        GetNumb = CDbl(Trim(Temp))
    End If
End Function
```

and then change your code

```
Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 3.5
```

to

```
Dn.Offset(, 1) = GetNumb(Dn.Value) + 3.5
```

**Explanation**: The function `GetNumb` extracts numbers from the string so

1. lm10 ~~> 10
2. LM120S ~~> 120
3. LM120 ~~> 120

Comment: I really appreciate your help and time, your code works great, however I am really sorry if i did not make this clear in my problem description, that i need to be able to change the codes for different lm values such as lm100 = 100.35 whereas lm100s = 103.5. I will have a got changing your code in the module.  Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: Dear @Siddharth Rout, I manage to implement select case L, which you cans see further down in the above code and I am trying to implement the same logic for the LM select case but the only problem I am getting, its not executing anything for the LM select case.  I hope this clarifies the problem.  I am still fiddling about with your code to make it work with my requirement. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Two things `Firstly` Change `If UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "LM"` to `If UCase(Left(Trim(Dn.Value), 2)) = "LM"` and `Secondly` you don't need `MID` statements anywhere to extract the number. Use the function that I have given...

Answer (score 1):

the `Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3))` evaluates to zero: **M10** starts with a letter, so ends the `val` process. That should be `Val(Mid(Dn, 3, 2))`

I am assuming your `select` statement is `Select Case UCase(Left(dn, 1))`. if you are not `UCase`ing the text, then it will not execute any code in the case statement

Comment: Thank you @Sean for your help and suggestion.  I am kinda struggling to get the select case Lm to work, if you could provide any direction of help into how to can i execute that chunk of code, i would really appreciate your help. thank you.

Comment: remove the `Select Case`: with so many **if/then/elseif** statements, the select case becomes redundant. for a little more readability, I would also suggest putting the `UCase(Dn)` into another variable, which removes a lot of the `UCase(Left(...`, and use something like `if MyValue Like "LM*" Then`

Answer (score 0):

Put some Debug.Print statements around your IF line to see what is going on, like so:

```
Debug,Print Dn
If UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "LM" Then
    Debug,Print "hi"
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 3.5
```

What is the Case "L" on the first line doing? Is your code being block from ever reaching the IF statement?